# RegionPlot3D does not plot "thin" regions?

Tags: plotting

Basically, I ultimately want to make something like this:

[image]

However, I am unsure of how to do this in *Mathematica*. I'm trying to do this via `RegionPlot3D`, and for starters, I was trying to draw a little disk in a sphere. But `RegionPlot3d` does not draws a sphere. For example:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1  && 
  z > 0 && 
  (x - Cos[π/4] Cos[π/3])^2 + (y - 
       Cos[π/4] Sin[π/3])^2 + (z - Sin[π/4])^2 <= 1/2, 
  {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

only makes a little blob. If I change this $1/2$ to, say, $1/10$, then it completely vanishes. Also, if I use `x^2+y^2+z^2 == 1` instead of `x^2+y^2+z^2 <= 1`, nothing is drawn. I tried to cheat and use `x^2+y^2+z^2 <= 1 && x^2+y^2+z^2 => 1`, but it didn't worked. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you using V9 or V10?  (The tools available are different.)

Comment: I am using version 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you would like?

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi/2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
   z > 0 &&
    (x - Cos[π/4] Cos[π/3])^2 + (y - Cos[π/4] Sin[π/3])^2 + (z - Sin[π/4])^2 <= 1/10],
  PlotRange -> 1.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Response to comment:

```
plot = SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r},
   (x - Cos[π/4] Cos[π/3])^2 + (y - Cos[π/4] Sin[π/3])^2 + (z - Sin[π/4])^2]}, 
 Mesh -> {{1/10}}, MeshShading -> {Red, Yellow}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> 1.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The apparent "seam" is the meeting of the boundaries `ϕ == 0` and `ϕ == 2 π`.  Since it's a sphere centered at the origin, there is a relatively easy fix. It isn't always so easy.

```
plot /. GraphicsComplex[pts_, stuff__] :> (GraphicsComplex[pts, stuff] /. 
   (VertexNormals -> _) :> (VertexNormals -> pts))
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can also specify the normals adding the option [`NormalsFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NormalsFunction.html).

```
SphericalPlot3D[..., NormalsFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, {x, y, z}]]
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. I hadn't thought about using `SphericalPlot3D`, in fact I know very little about the program, I'm still learning, thanks. However, if I wanted to make a plot of the whole sphere, stressing this little disk, what you'd think it would be better? Do everything separated and then using `Show`, or trying to figure out how `RegionFunction` works?

Comment: I found out that

`Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, 
    z},  (x - Cos[\[Pi]/4] Cos[\[Pi]/3])^2 + (y - 
        Cos[\[Pi]/4] Sin[\[Pi]/3])^2 + (z - Sin[\[Pi]/4])^2 <= 1/2]]`

works nice, too.

Comment: @IvoTerek You could also sometimes use `ParametricPlot3D`, which is suitable for surfaces that aren't graphs of an f(x,y), and allows you to specify the region in terms of parameters or the coordinates.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much for taking the time to explain `:)`

Comment: I have one last doubt (I hope). Using `RegionFunction` won't make the rest of the sphere appear. What made the trick was the `MeshFunction`, right?

Comment: @IvoTerek Right. `RegionFunction` controls what appears.  `MeshFunctions` and `MeshShading` control the styling of what appears.

Comment: Then this should have worked...

`ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] }, {u, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, \[Pi]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, 
     z}, (x - Cos[\[Pi]/4] Cos[\[Pi]/3])^2 + (y - 
        Cos[\[Pi]/4] Sin[\[Pi]/3])^2 + (z - Sin[\[Pi]/4])^2 <= 1/
     20]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 Boxed -> False]`

Comment: @IvoTerek Region functions are boolean (true/false values) and mesh functions are numeric.  So in your example, you should have had `MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u,   v}, (x - Cos[\[Pi]/4] Cos[\[Pi]/3])^2 + (y -
  Cos[\[Pi]/4] Sin[\[Pi]/3])^2 + (z - Sin[\[Pi]/4])^2]},
Mesh -> {{1/20}}`.  You might want to look at the doc page of each plot function; under "Options" you'll find examples that will show how to create nice illustrations.

Comment: Ok, I will look into it. Thank you again for the patience!