# Plotting less of a sphere

Tags: plotting

It is a follow-up question from [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76178/regionplot3d-does-not-plot-thin-regions).

I'll put the code at the end. So far, I have:[image]

Notice how nearer $z$ is to $0$, the more transparent the sphere is. I don't want to plot the whole hemisphere, but even if I make the domain for $u$ smaller, I don't get what I want, and I think the problem is because the other `Plot3D` there. Also, I am sure there is an intelligent way of getting the same figure here with less coding, using two `Plot3D` doesn't feel right, but it's the only way I can make it now.

- How can I plot less of the hemisphere?
- How can I optimize this mess?

(As a sidenote, it bothers me very much the fact that the figure "stretches" a bit, everytime I rotate it to have a better view.. what I am using `AspectRatio -> 1` and `BoxRatios -> {1,1,1}` for, then? Neither works.)

Thank you.

```
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u]}, {u, 
       0, \[Pi] - .5}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Mesh -> Automatic, 
      MeshStyle -> 
       Directive[GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.04`], AbsoluteThickness[0.`], 
        DotDashed], 
      PlotStyle -> 
       Directive[RGBColor[0.9500000000000001`, 1.`, 0.64`], 
        Opacity[0.1`]]], 
     Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -.8, .8}, {y, -.8, .8}, 
      Mesh -> Automatic, 
      MeshStyle -> 
       Directive[RGBColor[0.51`, 0.51`, 0.51`], AbsoluteThickness[0.`], 
        Dashing[{0, Small, Small, Small}]], 
      PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.6`, 0.6`, 0.6`], 
      RegionFunction -> 
       Function[{x, y, z, u, 
         v}, (x - Cos[\[Pi]/4] Cos[\[Pi]/3 - \[Pi]/2])^2 + (y - 
            Cos[\[Pi]/4] Sin[\[Pi]/3 - \[Pi]/2])^2 + (z - 
            Sin[\[Pi]/4])^2 <= 1/30]], 
     Plot3D[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -.8, .8}, {y, -.8, .8}, 
      PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.6`, 0.6`, 0.6`], Mesh -> Automatic, 
      MeshStyle -> 
       Directive[RGBColor[0.51`, 0.51`, 0.51`], AbsoluteThickness[0.`], 
        Dashing[{0, Small, Small, Small}]], 
      RegionFunction -> 
       Function[{x, y, z, u, 
         v}, (x - Cos[\[Pi]/4] Cos[\[Pi]/3 - \[Pi]/2 - 0.3`])^2 + (y - 
            Cos[\[Pi]/4] Sin[\[Pi]/3 - \[Pi]/2 - 0.3`])^2 + (z - 
            Sin[\[Pi]/4])^2 <= 1/30]], 
     Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Blue, 
       Point[{Cos[\[Pi]/4] Cos[(\[Pi]/3) - (\[Pi]/2) - .15], 
         Cos[\[Pi]/4] Sin[(\[Pi]/3) - (\[Pi]/2) - .15], Sin[\[Pi]/4]}]}], 
     AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: Something like `SphericalPlot3D[.99, {u, 0, \[Pi]/2}, {v, 6 Pi/4, Pi 2}, Mesh -> None,
  SphericalRegion -> True, RotationAction -> "Clip"]` instead your first plot does what you need?

Comment: You mean instead of the first `ParametricPlot3D` ?

Comment: Yes (*9 characters to go*)

Comment: Or use `SphericalRegion -> True, ImageSize -> 400` (with some fixed `ImageSize` to your liking.

Comment: @Kuba, after messing a bit more with your suggestion, I got something nice here, thanks. I read about `SphericalRegion` [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalRegion.html) and I understood that this function is what "fixed" the zoom. Is that right? (I'm a bit slow with softwares and english is not my first language, sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
c0 = Directive[RGBColor[0.9500000000000001`, 1.`, 0.64`], 
   Opacity[0.5`]];
{c1, c12, c2} = {RGBColor[0.6`, 0.6`, 0.6`], 
   RGBColor[0.6`, 0.6`, 0.6`], RGBColor[0.6`, 0.6`, 0.6`]};
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u]},
  {u, 0, π/2}, {v, 0, 2 π},
  PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> {{1/30}, {1/30}}, 
  MeshStyle -> 
   Directive[GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.4`], AbsoluteThickness[0.`]], 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, u, 
      v}, (x - Cos[π/4] Cos[π/3 - π/2])^2 + (y - 
         Cos[π/4] Sin[π/3 - π/2])^2 + (z - 
         Sin[π/4])^2], 
    Function[{x, y, z, u, 
      v}, (x - Cos[π/4] Cos[π/3 - π/2 - 0.3`])^2 + (y - 
         Cos[π/4] Sin[π/3 - π/2 - 0.3`])^2 + (z - 
         Sin[π/4])^2]},
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
    EuclideanDistance[{x, y, 
       z}, {Cos[π/4] Cos[(π/3) - (π/2) - .15], 
       Cos[π/4] Sin[(π/3) - (π/2) - .15], Sin[π/4]}] <
      0.5],
  MeshShading -> {{c12, c2}, {c1, c0}}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Cos[v], Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u]}, {u, 
   0, π}, {v, 0, 2 π}, 
  MeshStyle -> 
   Directive[RGBColor[0.51`, 0.51`, 0.51`], AbsoluteThickness[0.`], 
    Dashing[{0, Small, Small, Small}]],
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
    EuclideanDistance[{x, y, 
       z}, {Cos[π/4] Cos[(π/3) - (π/2) - .15], 
       Cos[π/4] Sin[(π/3) - (π/2) - .15], Sin[π/4]}] <
      0.5],
  PlotStyle -> None], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Blue, 
   Point[{Cos[π/4] Cos[(π/3) - (π/2) - .15], 
     Cos[π/4] Sin[(π/3) - (π/2) - .15], Sin[π/4]}]}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, 
 SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 0.1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Exporting the graphics causes the dashed line to disappear.  Isn't there a workaround on this site somewhere?

Comment: Thanks Michael, you're a life saver haha
Don't worry about the dashed lines, I pasted your code here and they show up all right. This works nice, too. I'm wondering how you got the part of the sphere to be plotted to be so... circular. Got to study what you have done, now.

Comment: @IvoTerek I used a `RegionFunction` that used the `EuclideanDistance` from the blue point.  If you'd like a different shape, change the `RegionFunction`.  -- Yeah, the dashed lines show up in *Mma*, but apparently not if you print it, export to PDF, etc.

Comment: Oh, I see. I just didn't got one thing. When you used the `MeshFunctions`, we have the ugly expressions involving sine and cosine, however, how do Mathematica knows that it's supposed to mesh the "inside" of these disks, and not "outside"? I mean, we dont have any ` <= 1/10 ` like in the other question you helped me with. I don't know if I expressed myself good enough here, sorry..

Comment: The option `Mesh` specifies values $m$ etc. for the mesh lines, which are curves of the form $f=m$ for a mesh function $f$.  The plot "starts" in the "lower left corner" of the plot domain, in your case `u == 0`, `v == 0`. As `u` and `v` increase, the plot crosses a mesh line.  The plot changes its mesh shading according to the `MeshShading` array: if it crosses the first mesh function, it changes row; if it crosses the second mesh function, it changes column.

Comment: I think I understood. The key point is `Mesh -> {{1/30}, {1/30}}`. If $f$ is the expression with sines and cosines, Mathematica will plot all the curves of the form $f=m$, from $m$ ranging from $0$ to $1/30$, that are contained in the sphere. It you had put, say, `Mesh -> {{1/30}, {1/2}}`, one of the circles would be way larger than the other one. That's it?

Comment: All right! Thanks very much for the help `:)`